# How to optimize this piece of Ionic Code

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've this piece of Ionic code that is loading to slow:

```
ionViewWillEnter(){
this.morePagesAvailable = true;
let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create();

loading.present();

this.post = this.navParams.get('item');

Observable.forkJoin(
  this.getAuthorData(),
  this.getCategories())
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.user = data[0].name;
    this.categories = data[1];
    loading.dismiss();
  });
}

  getAuthorData(){
    return this.wordpressService.getAuthor(this.post.author);
  }

  getCategories(){
    return this.wordpressService.getPostCategories(this.post);
  }
```

wordpressService is a getter from a REST API. Anyone can help me?

Thanks,
Rogério

Comment: What's slow? Dismissing the loading indicator or the API response? Are you on the UI thread when you call loading.dismiss(); because that will have serious negative side-effects.

Comment: @Dare, this is the WordPress Service:

`getPostCategorie(post){
    let observableBatch = [];

    observableBatch.push(this.getCategory(post.categories[0]));
    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);

  }

  getPostCategories(post){
    let observableBatch = [];

    post.categories.forEach(category => {
      observableBatch.push(category);
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observableBatch);
  }

  getCategory(category){
    return this.http.get(Config.WORDPRESS_REST_API_URL + "categories/" + category)
    .map(res => res.json());
  }`